# What are labels in graph database

Tags: neo4j, label

I'm new to graph databases and currently experimenting with neo4j. Can someone please help me understand:

1) what are labels exactly?
2) how/where they are used?
3) Why do we need them? Can we work without them?

I've read about labels but i'm not able to grasp this concept.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As you can read in [official doc](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#graphdb-neo4j-labels), labels represent a kind of class, or better: a type, of a node.

> A label is a named graph construct that is used to group nodes into
>   sets; all nodes labeled with the same label belongs to the same set.
>   Many database queries can work with these sets instead of the whole
>   graph, making queries easier to write and more efficient to execute. A
>   node may be labeled with any number of labels, including none, making
>   labels an optional addition to the graph.
>
> Labels are used when defining constraints and adding indexes for
>   properties (see Schema).
>
> An example would be a label named User that you label all your nodes
>   representing users with. With that in place, you can ask Neo4j to
>   perform operations only on your user nodes, such as finding all users
>   with a given name.
>
> However, you can use labels for much more. For instance, since labels
>   can be added and removed during runtime, they can be used to mark
>   temporary states for your nodes. You might create an Offline label for
>   phones that are offline, a Happy label for happy pets, and so on.

It's important to say that a node can have multiple labels. For example, the `node` representing Benedict Cumberbatch, could be labeled as: `Person`,`Man`,`Actor` and `British`.

You can query nodes by labels. It means that the Benedict Cumberbatch's `node` belongs to each one of those sets and it will be returned in each resultsets of the following queries:

```
MATCH (p:Person) return p
MATCH (p:Man) return p
MATCH (p:Actor) return p 
MATCH (p:British) return p
```

Labels are not mandatory but using them is considered a best practice to categorize your data and get them by types.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are used to name / categorize / classify / type nodes and relationships in a graph which does not represent entities of a single kind.

If all your nodes are e.g. people and all your relationships represent 2 people knowing each other, you don't need labels. But if you model something more complex, labels allow you to directly type the nodes and relationships, instead of having to rely on one or more properties of the node or relationship to describe that. It's a standard, immediately accessible way of describing the nature of the entity.

Or, in a more visual way, labels allow the Neo4j browser to display nodes of a different nature using different colors :)

[image: Neo4j browser]

Comment: AFAIK in version 3.0.x labels are reserved to [nodes](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#graphdb-neo4j-nodes) while [properties](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#graphdb-neo4j-properties) are both for nodes and relations. It is strange since I ever used a kind of labels also for rels (e.g. `[:Type_of_rel]`)

Comment: Relationships have a single type, whereas nodes can have multiple labels as you have noted in your answer. Yes, it's a bit of a language abuse to say relationships have a label, but it's the same concept, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know if it is only a matter of lexicon of if there are concrete difference from types and labels...